# Necessity & sufficiency of electric current on magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I know that there is some relationship between electric current and magnetism, but I am having trouble pinning down the exact relationship. Is electric current a necessary condition for the existence of magnetic field? And is electric current a sufficient condition for the existence of magnetic field?

In other words, is it true that "there is electric current if and only if there is a magnetic field"?

Answer (score 0):

NOOOOOOOO!

A changing electric field can also create a magnetic field. An example of this is *Electromagnetic field*. Recall that

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B}=\mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$
in absence of current density.